# Invoke method once in thumbling window but output all contained events

Tags: esper, nesper

How can I invoke a method like

```
select udf(a,b) from Event.win:length_batch(5)
```

and print the window of size 5 out again. Say i send the following events:

```
runtime.sendEvent(new Event(1,2));
runtime.sendEvent(new Event(3,4));
runtime.sendEvent(new Event(4,2));
runtime.sendEvent(new Event(6,8));
runtime.sendEvent(new Event(4,6));
```

and print them out in the same order after batching them. This means that the method invoked udf(a,b) shall only be executed once per batch. I have used the updatelistener, but I have to invoke it as a method event though i can get the desired result using the listener.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for "subscribers".

[Subscribers in doc](http://espertech.com/esper/release-5.5.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#api-admin-subscriber)

```
public void update(Event[] rows) {...}
```

Comment: EDIT: I see its alsmot the same way as adding a listener. I will test it out meanwhile. Thanks

Comment: but the update() method is invoked when setSubscriber(sub)?  this is almost the same as setting a listener. What I want is the method specified in my query to do what is possible with the update(Event[] new, Event[] old) method without the need for setting it as a subscriber. The update method is basically the same s the updatelistener no?